# Saving an object if not exists without using ObjectId (JS)

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to find a way to save a new object if one like it doesn't already exist with a specified custom ID.

I basically need to refresh a whole bunch of data every day but each item has its own ID set somewhere else (so not a parse `objectId`). I therefore can't use something like the standard `save` function as it'll just make a new record every time.

I've thought of trying to set the `objectId` of an object when its *first* created in the DB but I can't seem to do that... (Half expected this).

I've also thought of doing the obvious - checking if an object exists using a normal query but with a few thousand objects to compare, this will be very inefficient.

Any suggestions?

Maybe there is a save function or variation where its kind of "save or create depending if an object exists with this `value` in this `field`" :)

Thank you!

PS. I'm writing this within a Cloud Job - so JavaScript

Comment: Basically you want to save an object with specified `objectId`. Right?

Comment: @PedroMutter no - I want to save an object, if it doesn't already exist, WITHOUT using `objectId` ... Says in the heading `without using ObjectId`

Comment: My custom ID that I need to compare is called `offerId` if it helps

Comment: You will need to query the object to see if it exists before saving it, use the `offerId` to build your query. You can't no use the `objectId`, what you can do is customize it, did you try to set the `objectId` before saving?

Comment: @PedroMutter did you read my post at all?

Comment: Yes, many times, if you create an index on the `offerId` on your DB, it will not be so inefficient. But you can prefer to set the option https://parseplatform.org/parse-server/api/master/ParseServerOptions.html#allowCustomObjectId to `true` and set the `offerId` as your `objectId`. Then, when you save, it will update the object.

Comment: Thanks @PedroMutter . I've tried setting that flag to true (when initialising ParseServer in `index.js`) but when I try set it on my *new* object, I get the error `Error: Object not found.` .. Maybe I'm setting in incorrectly? I treat it as a normal attribute right? Thanks for your help

Comment: Bryon, it looks like it is only implemented in the server, not the js sdk. https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/8bc201d228f70e40a14ee29d4d0fb7e5a7cb001d/spec/rest.spec.js#L47.  There are no tests in the js sdk, so i assume that it hasn't been tested or implemented.

Comment: " I get the error Error: Object not found." Maybe if you handle this error and create a new object when the object is not found. Otherwise, just update...